# Firefox will not validate form data

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The following simple form with javascript with onclick button does not work in Firefox (I have version 7) but works fine in IE, Chrome, and Safari.
What am I missing?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function result() {
        alert(calc.input.value);
        }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="calc" action="">
    <input class="cInput" type="text" name="input" size="16" /><br/>
    <input type="button" class="cButton" name="seven" value="1" onclick="calc.input.value += '1'" />
    <input type="button" class="cButton" name="equal" value="=" onclick="result()" /><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: you must pass a function to onClick not a line of code and you should do event handlers in the header or external JS file not in the markup

Comment: there is a textfield and two buttons with captions `1` and `=`. when i click on button `1` it appends `1` to the text in the textfield while on clicking `=` button it shows a message containing the text in the textfield. So, what you want? I'm also have `Firefox 7`.

Comment: @tules - the onlick attribute is the body of a function that will be created by the handler, it does not need a function expression or declaration. There is not "should not" in regard to in-line handlers.

Comment: I disagree, unobtrusive JavaScript is considered best practice by pretty much everyone, it keeps the markup clean, you should always separate your behavior, appearance and content

Comment: @Tules - so all your documents use XML + style sheets for layout? HTML inherently mixes data, appearance and behaviour. Appeals to authority are no substitute for logic. Implementation strategies should be based on requirements and analysis of the options, not dogma.

Comment: no they use HTML like everyone else and no it doesn't "inherently mix appearance and behavior", explain how it does. Logic doesn't come into it, there's never a situation where it would be more beneficial to use inline handlers.

Comment: Tules: I don't think it's a good idea to make blanket statements like *"there's never a situation..."* You don't like inline handlers, that's fine. I agree with @RobG that dogmatic adherence to a concept like *"unobtrusive javascript"* isn't useful.

Comment: ok, give me 1 example where using inline handlers would be advantageous and I will withdraw the statement

Comment: @tules - consider adding a listener to ceratin inputs. One strategy is to add a class at the server, wait till the elements are in the client, then attach listeners dynamcailly. Or, on the server where the class was added, instead add the listener directly. No need for "DOM ready" or whatever, the listeners are already there. Adding a class attribute value is no different to adding an onclick attribute value. Whether that strategy suits you or not is up to you—it will suit some, not others.

Comment: @RobG: Great example. I agree on every point, and can not figure out why people have such a vehement opposition to inline handlers. Along the line of your DOM ready example, with inline handlers there's also zero time gap between the element being available and the behavior being available. This can be important. Anyway, with markup dynamically generated on the server, placing them inline is hardly obtrusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var calc;
    function result() {
        calc = document.forms['calc'];
        alert(calc.input.value);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your `<script> </script>` and @TomG's `<script> </script>`? I'd seen the output and both cases it is same.

Comment: You're really comparing document.forms['calc'].input vs. document.forms['calc'].elements['input']. They're both correct, but "elements" can also call in by the order they were entered in the form. e.g. document.forms['calc'].elements[2] would return the same result. "elements" contains every single form element which allows you to loop through them and make additional changes (such as disabling all form elements or changing their CSS style).

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

You are missing that IE adds element names and ids as global variables. Some other browsers in certain conditions (sometimes requiring the document to be in quirks mode) will copy that habbit, some wont.

So in IE (and some others) the form name *calc* is a global variable referencing the form and in other browsers it isn't.

The method in Dunuyadnd's answer is a robust, cross-browser way to get a reference to the form. The formal access method is:

```
document.forms['calc'];
```

Named form controls can accessed similarly:

```
document.forms['calc'].elements['input'];
```

or

```
document.calc.input;
```

Be careful with giving controls names that are the same as tags, it is a bit confusing. Also, if there is more than one control with the same name, you will get an [HTML collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) rather than a single element.

You may want to read about [HTMLForms](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357) and their related elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that really helped me figure out why mine did not work.  Would you be open to exchanging a few emails on some education subjects?  If yes, I am at pocketref@gmail.com.  Thanks...